# Do I need to distribute my product with the same license as the assets I use?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I like to use free images & graphics from the web and it looks like there are new types of licensing that I'm not sure how to use or understand. For example GPL, in software I have to open source my source. But when I use GPL licensed icon in my software what should I do?

The same go to LGPL, where in software I can only dynamic link to use in a Commercial app, but **when I use a LGPL icon in my software what should I do to enable me to use it free in Commercial app?**

Can I use Creative Commons in my Commercial app? What are the restrictions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues and not graphic design.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic, we have a few related questions you might want to look into: [How do I know which images are copyrighted and not?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7129/how-do-i-know-which-images-are-copyrighted-and-not), [Differences between “Royalty-Free”, “Public Domain”, “Creative Commons” etc](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/differences-between-royalty-free-public-domain-creative-commons-etc). Check the [creative commons](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=creative%20commons) questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [Creative Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license) (the most usual license of the kind for graphic assets), you can add any icons or graphics **that allow commercial use**.

For example, a Creative Commons license that is **NOT** NonCommercial is allowed for paid software. You generally (almost always) need to attribute the author, but using CC graphics doesn't necessarily mean you need to distribute your product with the same licence.

The restrictions will depend on the type of license the creator chose to distribute the art under, each piece will have a different one. You can check all the CC licenses here: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/

> A Creative Commons licensor answers a few simple questions on the path
>   to choosing a license — first, do I want to allow commercial use or
>   not, and then second, do I want to allow derivative works or not? If a
>   licensor decides to allow derivative works, she may also choose to
>   require that anyone who uses the work — we call them licensees — to
>   make that new work available under the same license terms. We call
>   this idea “ShareAlike” and it is one of the mechanisms that (if
>   chosen) helps the digital commons grow over time. ShareAlike is
>   inspired by the GNU General Public License, used by many free and open
>   source software projects.